# PHP replacing refusing to replace variable with it's value, although the value has been updated in code

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a PHP script that handles form validation for my submission system. There is however an error I have been getting and I can't wrap my head around how it works.
Basically:
There's a variable called `$resourceContent` which is updated according to what the type of the submission is (meaning if it's a file, the content will be the filename or if it's a link, it'll be the link). Now, `$resourceContent` has definitely been updated. If I run an `echo` before the line `echo $submission_success_html` the value is shown as correct. The `$submission_success_html` is a string of html code that builds the success page.
This is what this html looks like.

```html
$submission_success_html = "
<div class='submission_result'>
<h2>Your submission has been received!</h2>
<div class='resource_infopanel'>
       <b>Resource Name</b><span class='resource_property'>$resourceName</span>
       <br>
       <b>Resource Description</b><span class='resource_property'>$resourceDescription</span>
       <br>
       <b>Resource Type</b><span class='resource_property' id='resourceType'>$resourceType</span>
       <br>
       <b>Resource Content</b><span class='resource_property'>$resourceContent</span>
</div>
<br>
<span class='resource_infoflair'>Your submission will now be processed and reviewed. You can view the status for ongoing reviewals at the <a
        href='../html/reviewals.html'>resource reviewals page</a>.</span>
<hr>
<span class='resource_infoflair'>Your resource reference code is <b>$referenceCode</b></span>
</div>
";
```

Note: `$resourceName` and other stuff is replaced correctly, with their actual values. The `$resourceContent` and `$referenceCode` however, are replaced with their defaults, "" for the former and "unknown" for the latter.

Is there a mistake I made?

Here's the rest of the code for this script:

```php
<?php

include "connection.php";

// Posted submission data
$resourceName = $_GET['resourceName'];
$resourceDescription = $_GET['resourceDescription'];
$resourceType = $_GET['resourceType'];
$resourceLink = $_GET['resourceLink'];
$resourceFile = $_GET['resourceFile'];
$resourceContent = "";
$referenceCode = "unknown";

// Submission control
$allowSubmit = true;
$encounteredErrors = false;
$error_descriptions = "";
$error_array = array();

// Database connection
$dblink = "";

// HTML

$submission_success_html = "
<div class='submission_result'>
<h2>Your submission has been received!</h2>
<div class='resource_infopanel'>
       <b>Resource Name</b><span class='resource_property'>$resourceName</span>
       <br>
       <b>Resource Description</b><span class='resource_property'>$resourceDescription</span>
       <br>
       <b>Resource Type</b><span class='resource_property' id='resourceType'>$resourceType</span>
       <br>
       <b>Resource Content</b><span class='resource_property'>$resourceContent</span>
</div>
<br>
<span class='resource_infoflair'>Your submission will now be processed and reviewed. You can view the status for ongoing reviewals at the <a
        href='../html/reviewals.html'>resource reviewals page</a>.</span>
<hr>
<span class='resource_infoflair'>Your resource reference code is <b>$referenceCode</b></span>
</div>
";


$submission_failure_html = "
<div class='submission_result'>
       <h2>Your submission could not be processed!</h2>
       <h3>Here's what we think went wrong:</h3>
       <div class='resource_infopanel'>
              <ul>
              $error_descriptions
              </ul>
       </div>
       <br>
       <span class='resource_infoflair'>Your submission will now be processed and reviewed. You can view the status for ongoing reviewals at the 
            <a href='../html/reviewals.html'>resource reviewals page</a>.
       </span>
       <hr>
       <span class='resource_infoflair'>Your resource reference code is <b>$referenceCode</b></span>
</div>
";




echo "<head><link href='../css/responsepages.css' rel='stylesheet'><title>Processing...</title></head>";
process();






// Post the entry to the submission database
function submit(){
    global $referenceCode;
    global $resourceName;
    global $resourceDescription;
    global $resourceContent;
    global $allowSubmit;
    global $encounteredErrors;

    if ($allowSubmit) {
        $sql = "[unrelated]";
        $result = queryDatabase($sql);
        if ($result >= 0) {
            $encounteredErrors = false;
        }else{
            $encounteredErrors = true;
        }
    }
    finalize();
}

// Check the posted data to make sure it's all there
function checkData(){

    global $resourceName;
    global $resourceDescription;
    global $resourceType;
    global $resourceFile;
    global $resourceLink;
    global $resourceContent;

    global $encounteredErrors;
    global $error_array;
    global $allowSubmit;

    if (trim($resourceName) == ""){
        $error_array[] = "unset-name";
    }
    if (trim($resourceDescription) == ""){
        $error_array[] = "unset-desc";
    }
    if (trim($resourceType) == ""){
        $error_array[] = "unset-type";
    }
    if ((trim($resourceType) == "file" || trim($resourceType) == "both") && trim($resourceFile) == ""){
        $error_array[] = "unset-file";
    }
    if ((trim($resourceType) == "link" || trim($resourceType) == "both") && trim($resourceLink) == ""){
        $error_array[] = "unset-link";
    }

    // Validate data
    $resourceName = validateString($resourceName);
    $resourceDescription = validateString($resourceDescription);
    $resourceType = validateString($resourceType);
    $resourceContent = validateString($resourceContent);
    $resourceLink = validateString($resourceLink);
    $resourceFile = validateString($resourceFile);

    // Conclude

    if (count($error_array) > 0){
        $encounteredErrors = true;
        $allowSubmit = false;
        parseErrors();
        finalize();
    }else{
        $encounteredErrors = false;
        $allowSubmit = true;

        // Set the resource content to whatever it should be depending on the type
        if ($resourceType == "link"){
            $resourceContent = "<b>" . $resourceLink . "</b>";
        }else{
            $resourceContent = "File: <b>" . $resourceFile . "</b>";
        }
        generateReferenceCode();
        submit();
    }
}

// Strip the malicious shit from the strings.
function validateString($inputString){
    $inputString = trim($inputString);
    $inputString = stripslashes($inputString);
    $inputString = htmlspecialchars($inputString);
   return strip_tags($inputString);
}

// Check the error array and put the required descriptions for them into the description array.
function parseErrors(){
    global $error_array;
    global $error_descriptions;

    foreach ($error_array as $error){
        switch ($error){
            case "unset-name":
                $error_descriptions .= "<br><b>There's no name provided for the resource.</b>";
                break;
            case "unset-desc":
                $error_descriptions .= "<br><b>There's no description provided for the resource.</b>";
                break;
            case "unset-type":
                $error_descriptions .= "<br><b>An error prevented us from determining the type of your submission.</b>";
                break;
            case "unset-file":
                $error_descriptions .= "<br><b>A file was required by the selected submission type, but was not provided by you.</b>";
                break;
            case "unset-link":
                $error_descriptions .= "<br><b>A link was required by the selected submission type, but was not provided by you.</b>";
                break;
        }
    }

    finalize();
}

function generateReferenceCode(){
    global $referenceCode;
    global $encounteredErrors;
    global $error_descriptions;
    global $allowSubmit;


    $sql = "[unrelated]";
    $rowCount = queryDatabase($sql);
    $rowCount = $rowCount[0];

    if ($rowCount != null){
        if ($rowCount <= 9){
            $referenceCode = "#000" . strval($rowCount + 1);
        }else{
            if ($rowCount <= 99){
                $referenceCode = "#00" . strval($rowCount + 1);
            }else{
                if ($rowCount <= 999){
                    $referenceCode = "#0" . strval($rowCount + 1);
                }else{
                    $referenceCode = "#" . strval($rowCount + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $encounteredErrors = true;
        $allowSubmit = false;
        $error_descriptions .= "<br><b>The system was unable to generate a reference number due to an internal error.</b>";
    }

}

// Start the overall processing of the submission.
function process(){
    checkData();
}

// Echo out the correct html and finalize the operation.
function finalize(){
    global $encounteredErrors;
    global $submission_success_html;
    global $submission_failure_html;
    global $resourceType;
    global $resourceLink;
    global $resourceFile;
    global $resourceContent;
    global $referenceCode;

    if ($resourceType == "link"){
      $resourceContent = "<b>" . $resourceLink . "</b>";
    }else{
      $resourceContent = "<b>File: " . $resourceFile . "</b>";
    }

    if ($encounteredErrors){
      echo $submission_failure_html;
    }else{
      echo "ASS: $referenceCode";
      echo $submission_success_html;
    }
}
```

P.S: I've removed some unrelated stuff like SQL queries and the `queryDatabase()` helper function as they do not in any way use these variables nor have any relation to them.

Comment: What does the browser tools(f12) show you sending.

Comment: `$resourceContent` is set after you create `$submission_success_html` the variables are gone at that point and the HTML contains the values the variables had... not sure this the question though

Comment: ^ `$b = 1; $a ="b = $b"; $b = 11; // $a == 'b =1' NOT 11`  when you use a variable in a string, the replacement only happens once it is not a pointer or link.

Comment: So how would I go about creating the html?

Comment: Create the HTML after the variables are created, or put placeholders in the HTML and run a replacement on them later. Be certain placeholders are unique.

Comment: Okay - I moved the declarations into the last method to execute (and coincidentally the only one to use the values) - now the correct values are present. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Also, @user3783243, could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you to everyone who helped!
I am **not** a PHP master, I just use it for database connections and stuff
as it's the only way I know and have learned to use.

The fix to my problem is as follows:
I've moved the variable declaration to the only place they're really needed: into the `finalize()` method, so now the created variables have the correct values. Also, +1 new thing I learned about PHP.

EDIT: Whoops, some unintended self-praise slipped in somehow. I am, in fact, NOT a PHP master.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).